# The requested resource is not available. (jsp, servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've a login page where in I take the details of the user.

#### login.jsp

```
<form action="loginPage" method="post">
<table style="width: 30%">
    <tr>
        <th>user :</th>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="uid" id="uid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Password :</th>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="password"
            id="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit"
            value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>


</table>
</form>
```

#### login.java

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("uid");  
        String p=request.getParameter("password"); 
        System.out.println("here");

        ......  
     out.close();

  }
```

#### web.xml

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Page</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.ui.login.login</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Page</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/loginPage</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

the problem is when I click on the submit button I get an error saying,

```
>>The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: Take a closer look at URL of your login.jsp and URL of page you are requesting. Could you post them?

Comment: http://198.17.10.1:8080/Branding/jsp/loginPage?uid=aaa&password=aaaaa

Comment: Branding/jsp/loginPage

Comment: This will probably not solve anything but could you change name of your class to uppercase like `Login`? Also is it placed in `com.ui.login` package or `com.ui` package?

Comment: it is placed in  `com.ui.login`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Did you properly deployed your code on server? Can you access its `doGet` method by simply visiting it with browser?

Comment: No, I'm not able to access doGet method of my servlet class.

Comment: The action is not hitting my java class file.

Comment: Are you able to access `doGet` from *any* servlet?

Comment: Could you please put the directory structure image and URL using to access the web resource..

Answer (score 1):

You should write something to the response.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("uid");  
        String p=request.getParameter("password"); 
        out.write("here");
        out.flush();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the code as you said. Still same error. The action is not hitting my java class file.

Comment: The servlet is mapped to the `/loginPage` but action is not mapped to the servlet, this causes 404 error, or servlet is just in the worse case didn't start.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the your project directory structure and your URL,
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your form action and URL pattern in web.xml should match. / is missing in action attribute of your form tag.

Comment: `/` in `action` doesn't represents root of project, but root of server. So `action='/loginPage'` will represent `server/loginPage` instead of `server/project/loginPage`.